# Embedding window into another process

Tags: delphi, winapi

I have read some posts here on StackOverflow, but none has worked for me. Here is the code I am using to display the window of the standard Calculator on my form:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Tmp: Cardinal;
  R: TRect;
begin
  CalcWindow := FindWindow(nil, 'Calculator');
  if (CalcWindow <> 0) then
  begin
    GetWindowThreadProcessID(CalcWindow, CalcProcessID);

    Tmp := GetWindowLong(CalcWindow, GWL_STYLE);
    Tmp := (Tmp and not WS_POPUP) or WS_CHILD;
    SetWindowLong(CalcWindow, GWL_STYLE, Tmp);
    GetWindowRect(CalcWindow, R);

    SetForegroundWindow(CalcWindow);
    Windows.SetParent(CalcWindow, Panel1.Handle);
    SetWindowPos(CalcWindow, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOSIZE or SWP_FRAMECHANGED);

    AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadID(), CalcWindow, True);
  end;
end;
```

It does display the window on my form, but the glass border is lost and sometimes (especially when I move my form), it is hard to restore the focus to the embedded window (I need to click several times).

What may be causing this? Also, do you see any potential issues I may get into with using this method?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: Perhaps [following post](http://objectmix.com/delphi/729065-after-embedding-form-into-another-form-i-have-focus-problem-my-first-form-controls.html) by Peter Below is of relevance to you. I don't see you changing the calculater's borderstyle.

Comment: Thank you, but removing the caption bar makes the window lose its main menu.

Comment: It's notoriously hard to get this to work. Why not just embed a native Delphi calculator control?

Comment: I want to be able to embed any application, Calculator's just for an example.

Comment: @Pateman It's really really hard to get this right. I'd look for an alternative approach.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes, I noticed that. What would you suggest? I was thinking of taking a window snapshot using BitBlt and displaying it on my form, but I don't think this is a good solution.

Comment: @Pateman I'd suggest not trying to embed applications inside your app.

Comment: I agree with David anyway; @Pateman, about potential issues, I've tried both codes, from the question and from the answer and it does nothing on my computer (except bringing the calculator window to top). I'm using Delphi 2009 on Windows 7. The [SetParent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function fails on my system (result = 0). I've tried also run the application as administrator but the result's the same.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this code. I took it from one of my older source codes. You will lose glass frame, but main menu is visible, and I didn't notice any problem in setting focus back to the embedded app. You should be able to do so using SetForegroundWindow() API function. Whenever you move your container form, your embedded app loses focus, so you need to call SetForegroundWindow again to restore focus :

```
procedure ShowAppEmbedded(WindowHandle: THandle; Container: TWinControl);
var
  WindowStyle : Integer;
  FAppThreadID: Cardinal;
begin
  /// Set running app window styles.
  WindowStyle := GetWindowLong(WindowHandle, GWL_STYLE);
  WindowStyle := WindowStyle
                 - WS_CAPTION
                 - WS_BORDER
                 - WS_OVERLAPPED
                 - WS_THICKFRAME;
  SetWindowLong(WindowHandle,GWL_STYLE,WindowStyle);

  /// Attach container app input thread to the running app input thread, so that
  ///  the running app receives user input.
  FAppThreadID := GetWindowThreadProcessId(WindowHandle, nil);
  AttachThreadInput(GetCurrentThreadId, FAppThreadID, True);

  /// Changing parent of the running app to our provided container control
  Windows.SetParent(WindowHandle,Container.Handle);
  SendMessage(Container.Handle, WM_UPDATEUISTATE, UIS_INITIALIZE, 0);
  UpdateWindow(WindowHandle);

  /// This prevents the parent control to redraw on the area of its child windows (the running app)
  SetWindowLong(Container.Handle, GWL_STYLE, GetWindowLong(Container.Handle,GWL_STYLE) or WS_CLIPCHILDREN);
  /// Make the running app to fill all the client area of the container
  SetWindowPos(WindowHandle,0,0,0,Container.ClientWidth,Container.ClientHeight,SWP_NOZORDER);

  SetForegroundWindow(WindowHandle);
end;
```

You can call it this way:

```
  ShowAppEmbedded(FindWindow(nil, 'Calculator'), Panel1);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will try that plus another approach. What about child windows? Like, let's say the application opens the standard "Open file" dialog. Is there a way to keep it inside my application, too? What do you think?

Comment: Is it normal that fAttach, the 3rd param of the AttachThreadInput function is set to False ? Do that not means that you detach the threads ?

Comment: And another thing, as is, AttachInputThread must fail because you give the processId. I think you have to pass the ThreadId which is the return value of the GetWindowThreadProcessId

Comment: @loursonwinny, yes, you are right about False parameter. I first wrote a code in another procedure to detach from input, then copy\pasted that code in this procedure, and forgot to change the param to True.

Comment: @loursonwinny, Also for AttachThreadInput to fail, that is right, instead of passing the return value of GetWindowThreadProcessId, I used the returned process id in AttachThreadInput. Thanks for pointing this out. I updated the source code to fix this.

Comment: This code does not work anymore for the latest `Windows 10` and  `calc.exe`. This line is failing: `Windows.SetParent(WindowHandle,Container.Handle);` `GetLastError` returns `The parameter is incorrect.`

Comment: Looks like there is a bug in windows 10: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/df783714-2074-4127-a469-65964bf89e0a/setparent-to-the-window-of-another-process-fails-in-windows-10-but-works-in-window-7?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues

Answer (score 2):

For the sake of your sanity, and the sanity of your program's users, I think you'd better abandon this idea:

I tried to do exactly this thing with my own software (a window from 32-bit app embedded into 64-bit wrapper), and it never worked 100%, even using the tricks from the other answers you've got here.

1. It is very hard to make it work reliably, there are zillion little subtle issues that you'll never get right. If you're messing with windows of other applications, which are not aware of your manipulation, generally you're asking for trouble.
2. You're changing the way users expect Windows to behave. This will be confusing and unexpected for them.