# PDF add stamp annotation from image

Tags: delphi, pdf

I have very specific task in Delphi 2010 with PDF. After some days fight I want to ask your help.

Task:

1. open pdf in embedded viewer component on a form
2. define a rectangle with mouse on the document
3. add into the rectangle stamp annotation from image file (BMP or PNG or JPG). The image must be stretched to the selected rect.

I try to use next components:

1. Acrobat Reader ActiveX (TAcroPDF)
2. Gnostice PDF Toolkit
3. Debenu PDF library

At the moment I have crazy mix of problems.

1. Acrobat can show PDF and can show annotations but has a methods to select a rectangle and to add a stamp from an image file.
2. Gnostice can show PDF, can select a rectangle BUT can not add annotation from image file and can not read all new 1.7 PDF files.
3. Debenu has no viewer but can read all files, can add a stamp fro image file.

Now I have almoust working solution with using all 3 libraries (each for own part of the task).

But some times acrobat library (or any other) raises exception like "can not save file" and other ones. I killed all concurence for processed PDF file (at one moment only one component exists, all other is destroyed).

The main question is not to help to kill the exceptions... But show me a way or library to solve the task. Maybe exist a PDF library for Delphi which I do not know... and this wonderful library can solve the task.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi, I would suggest not using TAcroPDF all together - please see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081551/tacropdf-loses-resolution-after-form-has-resized/23111611#23111611 . furthermore - Debenu PDF lib can render, modify and save said PDF as an Image  - if you simply just have to show the user a preview - using debenu - create a temp image and show it in a TImage - Then use the rest of the Lib to save the actual PDF or do whatever.

Comment: @Ryno Thanks a lot. You have helped us a lot! Please make you answer as post. I will check it with great pleasure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using TAcroPDF all together.

please see this post: [TAcroPDF loses resolution after form has resized](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081551/tacropdf-loses-resolution-after-form-has-resized/23111611#23111611).

furthermore: 
Debenu PDF library can render, modify and save PDF files as an Image - if you simply just have to show the user a preview - using debenu - create a temporary image file and show it in a `TImage` - Then use the rest of the Library to save the actual .PDF or do whatever you need to.