# Open external application in own form

Tags: delphi, winapi, external

I use Delphi XE5 and want to show an external application within a Delphi form in an own component.
Is their any component which supports this?
How can realize this?

Comment: This rarely ends well; possible duplicate of [Embedding window into another process](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7611103/embedding-window-into-another-process) (misleading title)

Comment: Nope, this won't end well. Find a different way to solve your problem.

Comment: Unless the external application is explicitly prepared for this stunt, this will not work reliably. A common way for an application to document that it is prepared for this, is by exposing it's GUI as an ActiveX control.

Comment: I did such with "Windows.SetParent".

Comment: @Zam Indeed. This is the way. And it never ends well.

Comment: You could tell us a bit more about what you want to achieve by showing it inside your form, so maybe someone has a better idea (doing something else) to achieve your target.

Comment: See Raymond Chen's blog: [Is it legal to have a cross-process parent/child or owner/owned window relationship?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/04/12/10410454.aspx) and [Sharing an input queue takes what used to be asynchronous and makes it synchronous, like focus changes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2013/06/07/10424279.aspx) and [I warned you: The dangers of attaching input queues](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/08/01/8795860.aspx).